# How to make a list property writable in object initializer but read only in other places?

Tags: c#

Consider the following code snippet that does not compile.

```
class Class
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public int Frequency { get; set; }
}

class BoxAndWhisker
{
    private readonly List<Class> _classes = new List<Class>();
    public BoxAndWhisker()
    {
        Classes = _classes.AsReadOnly();
    }
    public IReadOnlyList<Class> Classes { get; } 

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BoxAndWhisker baw = new BoxAndWhisker
        {
            Classes =
            {
                new Class{ Value=1,Frequency=20},
                new Class{Value=2,Frequency=10}
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I want the property `Classes` to be read only right after `baw` is instatiated. How to do so? In other words, `Classes` must be writable in object initializer but read only in other places.

## Edit

I prefer object initializer to parameterized constructor.

Comment: Object initialisers are just syntactic sugar. There's nothing special about the code inside it, and you can't give the code in it special treatment. Have you considered using a constructor instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not pass `Class`es via *constructor*? E.g.

```
class BoxAndWhisker {
  public BoxAndWhisker(params Class[] items) {
    Classes = null != items
      ? new List<Class>(items).AsReadOnly()
      : throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(items));
  }

  public IReadOnlyList<Class> Classes { get; }
}
```

Then

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    BoxAndWhisker baw = new BoxAndWhisker(
        new Class { Value = 1, Frequency = 20 },
        new Class { Value = 2, Frequency = 10 }
    );

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You pass the `IList<Class>` instance to the `BoxAndWhisker` constructor and maintain a backing `IReadOnlyList<Class>` property

```cs
class BoxAndWhisker
{
    public BoxAndWhisker(IList<Class> classes)
    {
        if (classes == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(classes));

        Classes = new ReadOnlyCollection<Class>(classes);
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<Class> Classes { get; }
}
```

The usage example

```cs
BoxAndWhisker baw = new BoxAndWhisker(new List<Class>
{
    new Class {Value = 1, Frequency = 20},
    new Class {Value = 2, Frequency = 10}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the

```
set;
```

From the properties within

> Class

And make the Class have a Constructor which sets the initial values of the Properties, therefore they cannot be overwrote / changed

Answer (score 1):

The "object initializer" syntax in C# has no semantic difference compared to a property value assignment.

You can read [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers):

> The object initializers syntax allows you to create an instance, and after that it assigns the newly created object, with its assigned properties, to the variable in the assignment.

So this:

```
var foo = new Bar { Baz = "baz" };
```

is *completely equivalent* to:

```
var temp = new Bar();
temp.Baz = "baz";
var foo = temp;
```

So you cannot restrict the property assignment the way you want.
The only solution is to use a constructor as proposed in the other answers.